# authorize.net integration using php

Tags: php, authorize.net, recurring-billing, authorize.net-arb

We are implemented ARB subscription using authorize.net. it is successfully completed the subscription create. but how to get the subscription status using subscription id from authorize.net using php. because every day we will update the statuses of expired users details in our website. let me know is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ARBGetSubscriptionStatusRequest` in the ARB API to get the status of a subscription. If you use the [AuthnetXML PHP class](https://github.com/stymiee/Authorize.Net-XML)* it would look like this:

```
<?php
/*************************************************************************************************

Use the ARB XML API to create get a subscription's status

SAMPLE XML FOR API CALL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ARBGetSubscriptionStatusRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>yourloginid</name>
    <transactionKey>yourtransactionkey</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <refId>Sample</refId>
  <subscriptionId>1207505</subscriptionId>
</ARBGetSubscriptionStatusRequest>

SAMPLE XML RESPONSE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ARBGetSubscriptionStatusResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <refId>Sample</refId>
  <messages>
    <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
    <message>
      <code>I00001</code>
      <text>Successful.</text>
    </message>
  </messages>
  <status>active</status>
</ARBGetSubscriptionStatusResponse>

*************************************************************************************************/

    require('../../config.inc.php');
    require('../../AuthnetXML.class.php');

    $xml = new AuthnetXML(AUTHNET_LOGIN, AUTHNET_TRANSKEY, AuthnetXML::USE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER);
    $xml->ARBGetSubscriptionStatusRequest(array(
        'refId' => 'Sample',
        'subscriptionId' => '1207505'
    ));
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            table
            {
                border: 1px solid #cccccc;
                margin: auto;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                max-width: 90%;
            }

            table td
            {
                padding: 3px 5px;
                vertical-align: top;
                border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
            }

            pre
            {
                overflow-x: auto; /* Use horizontal scroller if needed; for Firefox 2, not needed in Firefox 3 */
                white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
                white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
                white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
                white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */ /*
                width: 99%; */
                word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
            }

            table th
            {
                background: #e5e5e5;
                color: #666666;
            }

            h1, h2
            {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            ARB :: Get Subscription Status
        </h1>
        <h2>
            Results
        </h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Response</th>
                <td><?php echo $xml->messages->resultCode; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>code</th>
                <td><?php echo $xml->messages->message->code; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Successful?</th>
                <td><?php echo ($xml->isSuccessful()) ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Error?</th>
                <td><?php echo ($xml->isError()) ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>status</th>
                <td><?php echo $xml->status; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h2>
            Raw Input/Output
        </h2>
<?php
    echo $xml;
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

*I am the author of that code

Comment: ok thanks for your reply.using this file i will check every user status daily using cron and update there subscription in my website.